# C# does not recognize JSON Array correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I'm struggling around a wired JSON Problem. I'm working with ASP C# and have a View sending a JS-Array to a Controller Action.

Here is the Structure of the JSON Data.

```
public class MapData
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string lng { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Routine I use to generate the JSON Array: for test purposes it doesn't generate valid MapData.

```
$("#pac-save").click(function () {
    var mapPoints = {
        Points: []
    }

    mapPoints.Points.push({
        lat:"asdf1",
        lng:"asdf1"
    })
    mapPoints.Points.push({
        lat:"asdf2",
        lng:"asdf2"
    })    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Map/saveGeplanteRoute",
        data:mapPoints
    }).done(function (dd) {
        alert("done");
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
})
```

Here's the Controller Action

```
public JsonResult saveGeplanteRoute(MapData data)
{
    var test = new MapData
    {
        Points = new List<Point>()
    };
    test.Points.Add(new Point() { lat = "asdf1", lng = "asdf1" });
    test.Points.Add(new Point() { lat = "asdf2", lng = "asdf2" });
    return Json(test);
}
```

The weird thing: When I stringify the data before sending it, it looks like this:

```
"{"Points":[{"lat":"asdf1","lng":"asdf1"},{"lat":"asdf2","lng":"asdf2"}]}"
```

The data coming back from Controller looks exactly the same when I stringify it: Why can't C# parse the Point data? The amount of point data is right as you can see below:

[image: JSON data]

I'll be glad on some advice pointing me to an error I did not found

Comment: What does your `Point` class look like?

Comment: Just noticed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change HTTP method to `POST` from `GET`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Map/saveGeplanteRoute",
        type: "POST",
        data: mapPoints
    }).done(function (dd) {
        alert("done");
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
```

`GET` method sends data using URL string which is not `JSON` friendly

Comment: Thank you very much..that did the Trick

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript where you generate the test data, put he lat and lng names between quotes: mapPoints.Points.push({ "lat":"asdf1", "lng":"asdf1" })

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the method on the $.ajax call yor issuing an http GET, and serializing the array in the url, that way you will have problems with the url length if you try to serialize a big array.

A better way could be send a post call, and serialize the array on the body of the call, this can be done that way

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/home/saveGeplanteRoute",
    data: mapPoints,
    method: 'POST'
})
.done(function (dd) {
     alert("done");
}).fail(function () {
     alert("error");
});
```